# Dojo EnhancedGrid: how to get selected column?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

In dojo enhanced grid, is there any way to get the selected columns?
Currently I can get selected rows by using grid.selection.getSelected() but I don't know how to get the selected column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Can be found with this: theGrid.focus.cell.field. This will give you the column name.
There is also theGrid.focus.cell.index and theGrid.focus.cell.layoutIndex if integer is what you need instead of column name.