# Dojo EnhancedGrid: How to get the index of selected column?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

If I click on the column header of dojo enhancedgrid, the whole column is selected.
I want to know the column index of such selected column.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447578/dojo-enhancedgrid-how-to-get-selected-column

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```
dojo.connect(grid,"onRowClick",function(event){
 var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
     dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem) {
            if (selectedItem !== null) {
                var id = grid.store.getValues(selectedItem, 'ID');
                     #whatever you want to do...
            }
     });

});
```